# ¿Como resolver el generar informes en Visual Studio con C# y Windows Form?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, visual-studio-2022

Buen día alguien podría ayudarme a resolver un problema que tengo.

Tengo un proyecto en Visual Studio, con C# y Windows Form, que es un pequeño puesto de ventas.

El menú principal lo tengo con paneles y los formularios hijos se acoplan en el panel, hasta ahí todo bien, **el problema lo tengo cuando genero informes que se me desordenan y no me salen bien**.

Si yo ejecuto un formulario especifico desde el program y genero el informe, me lo presenta bien.

A que se puede deber este problema y como resolverlo, porque siento que solo en mi PC me da ese error, ya que en la PC de un amigo, lo ejecuta bien.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que quiere decir que se desordenan???